# Javascript printing a popup window works in Firefox/Chrome but not Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, printing

The following lines of code create an html page in a browser popup and then prints the popup for the user:

```
function printPage(htmlPage)
{
   var w = window.open("about:blank");
   w.document.write(htmlPage);
   w.print();
}
```

This code successfully opens a print dialog in both Firefox and Chrome.  However, in IE, no print dialog is displayed.  Any suggestions?

I've also tried closing the popup after calling print(), as others have suggested fixes the issue:

```
function printPage(htmlPage)
{
   var w = window.open("about:blank");
   w.document.write(htmlPage);
   w.print();
   w.close();
}
```

To no avail.

Comment: What did the Developer Console tell you?

Comment: Weird; on IE8 the function exists under `w` and no error is thrown when invoking it, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`close()` the `document` before you try to `print()`.

```
function printPage(htmlPage) 
{ 
   var w = window.open("about:blank"); 
   w.document.write(htmlPage);
   w.document.close();
   w.print(); 
}
```

[Works in IE9](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/TkX4g/).

Comment: Thanks @josh3736 this worked!  The issue was I was attempting to close the window, not the document.  This now works.

Comment: Know it's an old one... but just curious if there some LOGICAL explanation of this behaviour.

And thanks - this helped me to fix an issue with Firefox!

Comment: The [spec says](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-98948567) "`close()` Closes a document stream opened by `open()` ***and forces rendering***".  So looks like the page has not yet rendered completely, so it cannot print.  Why? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯